# ordering the div as per data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a web app based on html angularjs

I have two div's

Div 1

```
<div class="box1" style="margin-top:20px;"> 
    <span ng-repeat="i in data" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">{{i.div1}}</span>
</div>
```

Div2

```
<div class="box1" style="margin-top:20px;"> 
    <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">{{i.div2}}</span>
</div>
```

in my controller

```
i.div1 is 20

i.div2 is 50
```

Now i have one dropdownlist

```
<select>
    <option>more</option>
    <option>less</option>
</select>
```

if a user clicks on more, div 2 should show above the div 1 and if user clicks less div 1 show above the div 2,

what i need to do

Comment: Use ng-hide and in the expression check what is selected.

Comment: show us something that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

You have to use `ng-show` directive.If condition is `true`, then `div2` will be shown,else, `div2` will be hidden.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data=[{"div1":20}];
   $scope.data2=[{"div2":50}];
  $scope.change=function(){
      var div1 =  $('.box1').eq(0).clone();
      var div2 = $('.box1').eq(1).clone();
      switch($scope.myValue){
        case "more":
            $('.box1').eq(0).replaceWith(div2);
            $('.box1').eq(1).replaceWith(div1);
            break;
        case "less":
            $('.box1').eq(0).replaceWith(div2);
            $('.box1').eq(1).replaceWith(div1);
            break;
            
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <select ng-change="change()" ng-model="myValue">
     <option>more</option>
     <option>less</option>
   </select>
       <div class="box1" style="margin-top:20px;"> 
            <span ng-repeat="i in data" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">{{i.div1}}</span>
    </div> 
   <div class="box1" style="margin-top:20px;"> 
        <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">{{i.div2}}</span>
   </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i said div 2 should be shown above div 1

like 

50

20

Comment: or else 20 50,

like this

Comment: @MumbaiWadala, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your more/less select doesn't need to pull anything from the server, it just needs to reorder what's already on the page, right?  That means it doesn't need to have anything to do with angular, just a very simple jQuery client-side event will do the trick:

You need a way to easily identify the two divs and the select client-side.  I've given them id's div1, div2, moreLessSelect.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("select#moreLessSelect").on("change",function(e){
    if ($(this).val() == 'more')
    {
        $("#div1").before($("#div2"));
    }
    else
    {
        $("#div2").before($("#div1"));  
    }
  });
});
</script>


<select id="moreLessSelect">
  <option value="more">More</option>
  <option value="less">Less</option>
</select>
<div class="box1" id="div1">angular div 1 contents go here</div>
<div class="box2" id="div2">angular div 2 contents go here</div>
```

(This will be more future-proof if you put the divs in an identifiable wrapper and use jQuery prepend or append function to move desired div to the top or bottom - well, there's loads of good ways to do it).